# Why does $n \choose r$ where $r = 1,n$ track $2^n$?

Tags: probability, combinations

I bashed together a clunky ruby script to find the sum total of $n \choose r$ where $r = 1,n$

I wanted to determine how many lines of output I could expect from a script that produces all possible combinations of an array.
I found that, for any $n$, the sum total $= 2^n$

```
$ ruby nchrsum.rb
6 choose 6 == 1
6 choose 5 == 6
6 choose 4 == 15
6 choose 3 == 20
6 choose 2 == 15
6 choose 1 == 6
6 choose 0 == 1
Total n choose r where n = 6 and r = 1,6:
       64
```

Holds true for all $n$ I tried -- but why?

Comment: In your array application, consider marking each array element with a 0 for "not taken" or a 1 for "taken".  There are two choices for each array element and therefore $2^n$ ways to mark the entire array.

Comment: $2^n = (1 + 1)^n = \sum_{i=0}^{n}\binom{n}{i}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's from the Binomial Theorem, expanding $(1+1)^n$

Comment: Perfect answer.

Answer (score 4):

Another explanation is to observe that, since $\,\dbinom nk$ is the number of subsets of $k$ elements in a set of $n$ elements, the sum  of all these coefficients ($n$  fixed) is but the number of all subsets of a set of $n$ elements – which is known to be $2^n$.

Comment: +1, I was just writing this myself. I feel like this explanation doesn't hide the fact that the identity can be obvious.

Comment: @Daniel Littlewood: Technically, the proof with $(1+1)^n$ is quite simple. But it doesn't explain, in my opinion, *why* it is so.

Comment: @Bernard: They're all explanations, I think; but different explanations can link to the reader's previous knowledge in different ways, which is why having multiple answers to a question can be so useful.

Comment: I totally agree with this point of view.

Answer (score 3):

One more explanation, given a CS or CS-like background: Consider the set of all $n$-bit numbers, from $0$ through $2^n-1$, inclusive; there are thus $2^n$ of them, by inspection.  (For instance, there are $2^3 = 8$ numbers from $0$ through $2^3-1 = 7: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7$.)

We could, also, count them as follows: How many of the numbers have no $1$ bits?  We choose none of the $n$ bits to be equal to $1$, so the answer is

$$
\binom{n}{0}
$$

How many of them have exactly one $1$ bit?  We choose one of the $n$ bits to be equal to $1$, so the answer is

$$
\binom{n}{1}
$$

How many of them have exactly two $1$ bits?  We choose two of the $n$ bits to be equal to $1$, so the answer is

$$
\binom{n}{2}
$$

And so on.

Of course, this way of counting must equal our first answer, so we can combine all of these separate counts to obtain

$$
\binom{n}{0}+\binom{n}{1}+\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n}{n} = 2^n
$$